# Make Cherry Pick not bring in history

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

So I've run into an issue with git where when I rebase or cherry pick a specific commit, I will get much more information than is in that specific commit. That issue is outlined really nicely in this question here:

[Am I misunderstanding git cherry-pick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121631/am-i-misunderstanding-git-cherry-pick)

And that is all well and good, I understand that it is picking up history because the commit I want depends on that history being there. What I don't get is how to get around it. I really don't want cherry pick to apply all of that history, what I would much rather is for it to use that history to figure out where the lines should go and then raise a conflict saying that it had to do something fishy in order to make it fit.

Is there any way for me to do this? The only way I have found is I can make a patch out of that commit and apply the patch, but I really want to be able to use cherry-pick and rebase for my trees.

To illustrate my example, you can iniitalize a git repository in an empty directory then add a text file with 1 line to your repository. Then add 3 more lines to the file in 3 seperate commits, so you will have 4 commits and 4 lines in your file. My file lookes like:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
```

Now do git checkout HEAD~3 so that you have only

```
line 1
```

Then call git cherry-pick HEAD and you will get a conflict. Why this happens is outlined in the link I posted above. Your file will look like this:

```
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
line 2
line 3
line 4

>>>>>>> 6fe905b... Commit 4
```

But this is bad because if this comes up in a real example, your merge conflict is saying that Commit 4 had Much more stuff than was actually in Commit 4. So is there any way for me to fix it so that cherry-pick will give me a more logical merge conflict? In my real world issue where this is coming up, it's occuring when I am doing a rebase. If I can fix this for cherry-pick, my logic is that the underlying cause for this should be fixable for rebase as well.

Comment: Re edit: you may want to set `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note: edited to add `diff3`, re the latest edit to the question; see bottom-most section]

The `cherry-pick` command takes, as its arguments, a *list* of commit IDs:

> git cherry-pick [--edit] [-n] [-m parent-number] [-s] [-x] [--ff] <commit>...

But you say you are using:

```
git cherry-pick branch-name commit-hash
```

That means you're asking git to pick *two* cherries: the one associated with the tip of the named branch (the SHA-1 ID to which `branch-name` resolves), and the one associated with the given `commit-hash`.

To put it another way, run this first:

```
git rev-list --no-walk branch-name commit-hash
```

The output from `rev-list` is what `cherry-pick` "sees", in effect.

---

`git rebase` does something rather more extensive than `git cherry-pick`.  Typically, people run this to move a "branch arm" (this is a term I just made up) from one point to another:

```
A - B - C - D - E   <-- origin/master
          \
            K - L   <-- local
```

This kind of situation arises all the time when you make a local branch to do some work (commits `K` and `L` on `local`), and meanwhile someone else does their own work (commits `D` and `E` on master) and you decide you want to "re-base your `local` branch" on top of their work, so you do something like:

```
git fetch
```

(then you look around and see commits `D` and `E`, so you want to bring your local `master` up to date):

```
git checkout master
git merge --ff-only origin/master
```

(local master now up to date, now you decide to rebase branch `local`):

```
git checkout local
git rebase master
```

Rebase is basically an automated "repeatedly cherry-pick until done, then change branch labels" operation.  Given the commit graph I drew above, it starts by doing a detached-`HEAD` `git checkout` to get to commit `E`, then it does a `git cherry-pick` of commit `K`, repeats for commit `L`, and (if all goes well) finally adjusts the local branch label `local` to point to the last of the new cherry-picked commits:

[start]

```
A - B - C - D - E       <-- master, origin/master
          \
            K - L       <-- HEAD=local
```

[step 1, get `HEAD` set directly to `E` and then cherry-pick a copy of `K`, giving:]

```
A - B - C - D - E       <-- master, origin/master
         \       \
          \       K'    <-- HEAD [detached]
           \
            K - L       <-- local
```

[step 2, cherry-pick a copy of `L`, giving:]

```
A - B - C - D - E       <-- master, origin/master
         \       \
          \       K'-L' <-- HEAD [detached]
           \
            K - L       <-- local
```

[done with cherry pick sequence, move label, giving:]

```
A - B - C - D - E       <-- master, origin/master
         \       \
          \       K'-L' <-- HEAD=local
           \
            K - L       <-- [no label, abandoned]
```

The repeated cherry-pick sequence will stop (with a merge conflict) if needed, but if so, it leaves files in the `.git` directory to remember what it was doing and how far along it had gotten, so that you can run `git rebase --continue` after you fix the problem.

Essentially, the two big differences between `cherry-pick` and `rebase` are:

- `cherry-pick` uses `--no-walk` when asking `git rev-list` for the commits to pick up; `rebase` walks commits (though `rebase` shuffles arguments around so you can't just run `git rev-list` to see them in advance this way).
- `cherry-pick` never moves branch labels; `rebase` does when done.

---

The new example in the question for illustrating the diff issue is slightly broken: when you `git checkout HEAD~3` and then try to `git cherry-pick HEAD`, `HEAD` will refer to the commit whose ID is `master~3` at that point.  But `cherry-pick master` will do the trick.  Here's an example where I set `merge.conflictstyle` to `diff3` so that you can see the specifics of what `cherry-pick` is applying:

```
$ echo 'line 1' > file && git add file && git commit -m 'add file with 1 line'
[master 72f46c5] add file with 1 line
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file
$ echo 'line 2' >> file && git add file && git commit -m 'add line 2' 
[master 134cdd1] add line 2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ echo 'line 3' >> file && git add file && git commit -m 'add line 3'
[master e8634fc] add line 3
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ echo 'line 4' >> file && git add file && git commit -m 'add line 4'
[master 50810b6] add line 4
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git checkout master~3
...
HEAD is now at 72f46c5... add file with 1 line
$ git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
$ git cherry-pick master
error: could not apply 50810b6... add line 4
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
$ cat file
line 1
<<<<<<< HEAD
||||||| parent of 50810b6... add line 4
line 2
line 3
=======
line 2
line 3
line 4
>>>>>>> 50810b6... add line 4
```

Some like the `diff3` style enough to `git config --global` (I'm still considering this myself :-) ).

Comment: Awesome answer but it doesn't really address my issue exactly though there are some nice take aways on cherry pick and rebase that I thank you for. I added more information to my question to better illustrate my issue, I'm having a hard time communicating my problem I think. Unless what you are saying is I can't do what I want to do, which is cherry pick my commit and not have the conflict look misleading.

Comment: That is awesome that makes my conflict readable. For bonus points, is there a way for me to set it so that it can resolve these conflicts automagically? As in, add the difference between the cherry picked commit and it's parent so that I get a result of line1 \n line4?

Comment: No, that's just a bit too hard for git, it really wants to see the same context.  There are some *other* cases where using the `patience` merge strategy helps (but not this particular one).

Answer (score 0):

The respective results of running `git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` are not typically the same.

Running `git rebase` typically rewrites history and can appear to move entire branches around. This is likely the source of the undesired history you are seeing.

In contrast, `git cherry-pick` replays the delta from one or more commits elsewhere in a repository’s history. The typical use case is cherry picking a single commit to create another new commit. I would need to know more specific information about the commands you are running to see how you might be frustrated with the results.

A useful command for condensing a multi–commit topic branch into a single commit is `git merge --squash`. The alternative is a rebase followed by another interactive rebase.

Comment: I added a bit of info. The problem I am seeing is with both cherry-pick and rebase, and happens in the exact same way. It's a single file which gets more changes than you would expect from a cherry pick. Rebase will have the same effect on that individual file.