# Git cherry-pick doesn't work as expected (integrates more than one commit)

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I try to understand git cherry-pick command but it seems not to work as expected.

My git tree :

```
A -- B -- C -- H -- I -- J       MASTER
            \
             D -- E -- F -- G    TEST
```

I just want cherry-pick F in master branch, so I did :

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <sha-F>
```

The result is Git try to add not only F but also D and E.
Can somebody explain me why ? And what I'm doing wrong ?

Thx for help

Comment: How do you know that git is trying to add D and E?

Comment: I forgot to precise that all the commits are in the same file. When I use "cherry pick", I have a conflict and I can see in the file that Git try to integrates all the lines added from D to F. Maybe it is the correct behavior ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121631/am-i-misunderstanding-git-cherry-pick and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337192/make-cherry-pick-not-bring-in-history